# Removing 3 nested if-then-else

Tags: php

I'm seeing this code as the equivalent of a mathematical permutation. It tries to set the value of `$d` based on a combination of `$a, $b, $c`. Right now it's being done with 3 nested if/then/else. Any other way the same thing can be done more efficiently?

```
if ($a === true) {
    if ($b > 0) {
        if ($c === true) {
            $d = 6;
        } else {
            $d = 2;
        }
        $e = $b;
    } else {
        if ($c === true) {
            $d = 4;
        } else {
            $d = 0;
        }
    }
} else {
    if ($b > 0) {
        if ($c === true) {
            $d = 5;
        } else {
            $d = 1;
        }
        $e = $b;
    } else {
        if ($c === true) {
            $d = 7;
        } else {
            $d = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice there's `$e = $b;` at the end of

```
if ($a === true) {
    if ($b > 0) {
} else {
    if ($b > 0) {
```

I think I will just remove it out of the whole look and say

```
if ($b > 0) {
```

Any error with that logic for `$e = $b;`?

Comment: Somewhat off-topic (and potentially not relevant), but you do realise that you're allowed to use meaningful variable names in PHP? (Fortran was *such* a long time ago.) :-)

Comment: @middaparka, it's just a permutation, so a combo of `$a, $b, $c`. I think in this case, it's much simpler than giving them names. I wouldn't do `$a, $b, $c` for a real software though :)

Comment: Thought as much - just checking. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$vals = array(3,7,1,5,0,4,2,6);
$d = $vals[((int)($a === true) << 2) + ((int)($b > 0) << 1) + (int)($c === true)];
if ($b > 0) {
    $e = $b;
}
```

This takes each condition as a bit in a 3 bit value to determine the index of the value for *d*:

```
index = a·2^2 + b·2^1 + c·2^0
```

Each condition yields a boolean value that is converted to integer (see [*boolean* to *integer* conversion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting.from-boolean)) and then shifted according to the position of the bit it represents (see [shift left operator `<<`](http://php.net/language.operators.bitwise)).

Comment: @Gumbo, I'm sure this is very good, but I have no idea what it means.

Comment: @switch: I’ve added an explanation.

Comment: +1 The lookup table is a nice touch to keep the math simpler.

Comment: @Gumbo, Is reversing the array and bit shift correct too? `$vals = array(6,2,4,0,5,1,7,3);` 
`$d = $vals[((int)($c === true) << 2) + ((int)($b > 0) << 1) + (int)($a === true)];`

Comment: @sameold: No, you would need to invert the conditions too: `$vals[((int)($c !== true) << 2) + ((int)($b <= 0) << 1) + (int)($a !== true)]`.

Comment: @Gumbo, Good algorithm. Bookmarked. I can think of a few places in my code where I can use this myself.

Answer (score 2):

Just write the assignments (in order) as:

```
$d = 0 + 2 + 4
$d = 0 + 2
$d = 0 + 4
$d = 0
$d = 1 + 4
$d = 1
$d = 1 + 2 + 4
$d = 1 + 2
```

then you just have

```
$d = ($a === true ? 0 : 1) + ($c === true ? 4 : 0) + (($b > 0) === $a ? 2 : 0)
if ($b > 0)
  $e = $b
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a completely different approach with a bit flag thing.

- Bit 0: 1 if `$a == true`
- Bit 1: 1 if `$b > 0`
- Bit 2: 1 if `$c == true`

This will give you eight different values, that you can compute and compare easily.

Pseudo-code:

```
d =  (a     ? 1 << 0 : 0)
   | (b > 0 ? 1 << 1 : 0)
   | (c     ? 1 << 2 : 0)
```

Edit: forgot to warn that this won't match with your current `$d` values, you'll have to remap or rework the above if that's possible. Just a suggestion.

Comment: You should use `|` instead of `+` when dealing with bits.

Comment: I agree with the advice to use a proper bit field. It would be more meaningful if each condition represented a single bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a = $argv[1] ? true : false; 
$b = $argv[2];
$c = $argv[3] ? true : false;
$d = 0;
$e = null;

// compute
if ($b > 0) {
  $e = $b;
  $b_bool = true;
}
else {
  $b_bool = false;
}

if (!$a) $d += 1;
if (!($a ^ $b_bool)) $d += 2;
if ($c) $d += 4;

echo "$d $e\n";
```

If you could rearrange the data a bit the XOR wouldn't be needed.

And obviously this could be easily compacted a bit with a single assignment, but I left it expanded to be more readable.